# Error reading file

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

What should be done to solve it?
I have edited the `board.txt` file and none of my codes are getting verified 
it shows this error:

> "Error reading file (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt:0): Invalid line format,
>   should be 'key=value' "

Comment: it is obvious that you made a mistake editing the file .... revert the file to its original content

Answer (score 1):

You can either reinstall the Arduino IDE (it will replace the file), or copy the original code back in the file (if you have a copy somewhere).

See the link: https://code.google.com/archive/p/arduino/wikis/Platforms.wiki for more background in case you are interested.

(note: I cannot copy the content of the file in the answer since it is more than 30000 characters.)